# How to run Airtest Automation project (.air) using python?

Tags: python, automation

I am using Airtest IDE for android application automation. For it I prepared a Airtest project(.air) with automation steps.
The problem is I want to run this project on two Android devices but in airtest we can only run on one device at a time.

So, I tried opening it in two different Airtest IDE windows and manually running it on one device in one window and on other device in other window.

I want to automate these step using Python. I want to open both the windows using python and running in one device with one window and other device with other one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your python code and in `airtestide`.

```
connect_device("Android:///device name")
```

adb device will give you device name

by using this `connect_device  = script` will only run in that particular device only

and add another device for your `ide`.